# How to inject javascript into page, from a Firefox add-on, and run it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension (add-on) to allow users to annotate any page with text and/or drawings and then save an image of the page including the annotations. Use cases would be clients reviewing web pages, adding feedback to the page, saving the image of this and emailing it back to the web developer or testers taking annotated screenshots of GUI bugs etc.

I wrote the annotation/drawing functionality in javascript before developing the extension. This script adds a `<canvas>` element to the page to draw upon as well as a toolbar (in a `<div>`) that contains buttons (each `<canvas>` elements) for the different draw tools e.g. line, box, ellipse, text, etc. This works fine when manually included in a page.

I now need a way for the extension to:

1. Inject this script into any page, including pages I don't control.
2. This needs to occur when the user invokes the extension, which can be after the page has loaded.
3. Once injected the `init()` function in this script that adds the canvas and toolbar elements etc. needs to be run somehow, but I can't determine how to call this from the extension.

Note that once injected I don't need this script to interact with the extension (as the extension just takes a screenshot of the entire document (and removes the added page elements) when the user presses the save button in the extension chrome).

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I managed to inject the code into the page but I haven't figured out how to invoke it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this is how I solved my problem by setting the onload attribute to call the init function in the script that's being appended to the page.

```
var myScript = top.window.content.document.createElement('script');
myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
myScript.setAttribute('src','chrome://path/to/script.js');
myScript.setAttribute('onload', 'firefoxInit()');
top.window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
```

Comment: @euphoria83 See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519

Comment: In Firefox 4, not sure about 3, it's not allowed to link directly yo chrome:// URLs.

Comment: the onload event doesn't fire when tested on firefox 31. Is that how its supposed to behave ?

Comment: Does anyone know the 'src' equivalent for a Firefox Addon?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Greasemonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) :

> Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by
>   using small bits of JavaScript.
>
> Hundreds of scripts, for a wide variety of popular sites, are already
>   available at http://userscripts.org.
>
> You can write your own scripts, too. Check out
>   http://wiki.greasespot.net/ to get started.

Comment: @donohoe : **I really dislike the greasmonkey idea.** They script is loaded only when the page finished to load. On many sites, the page load can never end so the script is never launched *(this is greasmonkey design)*. It is important to put more ***grained control*** and Opera folks [understood it](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/specs/#evlistener) in the past *(They no longer does:-/)*. Users can really get mad if they need to wait up to 50 mins to get the script executed.